# What is the easiest way to install PostGIS?

Tags: postgresql

**What is the easiest way to install postgis on Ubuntu Server 11.10?**

```
apt-get install ...
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

this package is not available in the official repository so you can use a ppa for a quick and dirty installation.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuGIS

for Ubuntu 11.10 Oneiric the packages are only available in the unstable version of this PPA, to install and use this ppa

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable
```

to update your software list and install the package you are interested of

```
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install postgis
```

Comment: OKAY SO FAR SO GOOD. now how do i create a db? (+1).. where did it get installed?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/84762/how-do-i-configure-postgis

Comment: this is a website about Ubuntu, search for a tutorial or something like that on the internet for extra information that does not belongs to the topic of this website.

Comment: agreed... probably belongs in the GIS SE

Comment: I can't find any up-to-date tutorials.

Answer (score 3):

As noted in Micro's answer, your best bet for installing PostGIS is the [UbuntuGIS PPA](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuGIS). As of the time I'm writing they are distributing PostgreSQL 9.1 and PostGIS 2.0.1. Starting with these versions it became [much easier](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/39229/1271) to set up a PostGIS database.

Once PostGIS is installed, how do you create a PostGIS database? Ignore any old docs you find about using `template_postgis` or importing a bunch of `.sql` scripts in to your database. All you need to do in the new way is

```
createdb foo
psql -d foo -c 'create extension postgis'
psql -d foo -c 'create extension postgis_topology'
```