# How do i configure postgis

Tags: postgresql

PostGIS has been [installed on ubuntu server 11.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84753/easiest-way-to-install-postgis)...

Now how do i create a database, admin user, etc..

where does it get installed `ls -l /etc/...`?

Answer (score 3):

When you are programming something new the docs came first than everything else.

According to the PostGIS description this software only adds a support to a particular type of object, in other terms and simplifying the concept, PostGIS is only a "plugin" for PostgreSQL. Considering this your question is about learning PostgreSQL and not really about PostGIS so i suggest to read the PostgreSQL documentation http://www.postgresql.org/docs/ or search on the internet for PSQL tutorial.