# Installing PostGIS on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: 15.04, postgresql

When executing this command

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.4-postgis2.1 pgadmin3
```

to install PostgreSQL with PostGIS I get the following error:

```
postgresql-9.4-postgis-2.1 : Depends: libgdal1 (>= 1.9.0) but it is not going to be installed
```

The only solutions I could find online are related to Ubuntu 12 and are outdated, but maybe here knows how to fix this?

Comment: Unfortunately, Ubuntu has 2 libgdal libraries disponible and they are incompatible: libgdal1h (Ubuntu default version) and libgdal (OsGeo version). If you force to install libgdal, for example, QGIS will be broken.

Answer (score 0):

As you, I couldn't install `postgresql-9.4-postgis2.1` package but, a while after, I could install `postgresql-9.3-postgis2.1` with `postgis-2.1` and `libgal1h` (Ubuntu version of `gdal`). See below images:

[image]

The broken dependencies were definitively solved:

[image]

As you can see, the `postgis` extension was efectively created for `brasil_estados` database.

[image]

It is not totally functional. Next time that you open Synaptic, the packages appear as  broken dependencies. It's impossible to upgrade the system with `postgresql-9.3-postgis2.1` and `postgis-2.1` installed.

Answer (score 0):

I also had problems installing PostGIS on Ubuntu 15.04, but eventually got it to work. I tried a few different things (eg, this easy looking example for earlier version of Ubuntu: `http://askubuntu.com/questions/84753/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-install-postgis`) so not sure what all will be relevant, but here are the steps that worked for me:

1. try installing postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1 with `sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1` (NOTE: it looks like postgresql-9.4 does not yet have postgis for ubuntu 15.04, as seen with `apt-cache search postgresql-9`)
2. (If you DO NOT get an error skip step 3) assuming you get an error like "missing dependency... libgdal1 will not be installed" then go find your sources.list in /etc/apt as mentioned [on this github issue](https://github.com/cccs-web/core/issues/96) and remove any `http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/` repositories (as stated on github link, issue is ubuntugis is not supported on trusty so need to remove it as an option). Install with same `sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1` command and ideally you'll get no errors...
3. Test connection to postgresql with 'psql' (NOTE: may need to set connection details appropriately, see [psql options](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/app-psql.html))
4. Confirm you can add postgis with 'CREATE EXTENSION postgis;' in psql, view added extensions with '\dx'

Hope this helps!